# Split and rejoin microphone cables

Tags: audio, microphone, soldering

I have 2 microphones but (for a reason) I need to combine one of the two cables inside the cable sheathing and split them later again.

So it would look like this:

```
MIC1  MIC2
 ||    ||
 |\    /|
 | \  / |
 |  \/  |
 |   |  |
 |   |  |
 |  /\  |
 | /  \ |
 |/    \|
 ||    ||
```

The question is now before I destroy the microphones:

1. Is it possible in general?
2. Can I solder GND and the signal-cable or which one?

Comment: While you can join GND (ground) wires - it is a bad idea. All low level analog signals should have a single point of grounding, otherwise there could be returned current loop.

Comment: You can buy 2 conductor + shield cable, e.g. http://www.allelectronics.com/item/2cs22/2-conductor-shielded-cable-w/drain/1.html, which might make a more satisfactory solution. Connect both braids to the shield and signal cables to each conductor.

Comment: Recommendation: don't destroy the mic cable.  Do whatever you need to do in something you attach to the cable like an extension or adapter.

Comment: Serious question: What are you hoping this will actually achieve? It sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not here to question why you would want to do this, so here's my answer.

Because of the way electricity works, you can solder the ground cables together.  The signal cables are what actually carry your sound, and the ground is just a return for the electricity to come back to.  However, if you do this, you will most likely get bleed over from one microphone to the other.

So yes, you can solder the cables just like in your picture, provided that the 2 cables you are meshing together are the ground cables (usually black).  Just don't expect the highest quality when doing so.